# ruby ivar outside a class

Tags: ruby

I can define @some_ivar outside a class. To which class does this ivar belong to and what is it's scope?

For example,
I can say in example.rb

```
@var = "Hi"
```

and in irb, I can require example.rb and access @var

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That var belongs to a top-level object called `main`.

```
$ irb
1.9.3p0 :001 > @var = 'Hi'
 => "Hi" 
1.9.3p0 :002 > self
 => main 
1.9.3p0 :003 > @var
 => Hi
```

`main` is basically an object with an interesting property: any method defined in its context (outside of "normal" classes) becomes available to all objects.

```
$ irb
1.9.3p0 :001 > def foo
1.9.3p0 :002?>   1
1.9.3p0 :003?> end
 => nil 
1.9.3p0 :004 > Object.new.foo
 => 1 
1.9.3p0 :005 > "".foo
 => 1
```

Comment: At least in Ruby 1.9.2, methods defined in `main` seem to be private to the objects (-> `private method 'foo' called for #<Object:0x0000020bf539c8>`).